# Вычислить общую длительность активности пользователя

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, время

Дан датасет, где представлены имена пользователей и время, в которое они начали отвечать на вопрос. Нужно узнать, сколько всего минут каждый участник затратил на обдумывание. Логика такая: как только один человек ответил на вопрос, начинается отсчет времени для другого участника. Так Max, затратил 6 секунд на обдумывание, после этого начался отсчет для Alex.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовала сделать это через `df.groupby('name').sum()`, но в этом случае расчеты неверны. Считается не общее время, затраченное пользователем на обдумывание, а суммируются значения начала отсчета времени.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, для Мax правильное значение должно выглядеть так: 00:01:31

Comment: Вы не должны публиковать код (или сообщения об ошибках/исключениях, файлы журналов, файлы конфигурации, файлы проекта или что-либо еще, что представлено в текстовой форме) в виде изображения, потому что:

Код или примеры данных в изображениях нельзя скопировать и вставить в редактор и скомпилировать, чтобы воспроизвести проблему...https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Я ничего не понял из этого объяснения. Попробуйте объяснить на двух пользователях и дать для них желаемый результат. Пока у меня никакой из вариантов объяснения не бьётся с результатом, который вы говорите должен быть.

Comment: Колонка time фиксирует время начала "обдумывания" пользователем конкретного вопроса. Например, Max начал обдумывать первый вопрос в 00:00:01, а ответил на него в 00:00:07. Т.е обдумывание у него заняло 6 секунд. Далее Alex, отсчет его времени начался в 00:00:07 и прекратился в 00:02:03. Т.е. он свой вопрос обдумывал 1 минуту 56 секунд. Задача состоит в том, чтобы посчитать общую продолжительность обдумывания всех вопросов для каждого пользователя. 
У Max  2 вопроса, общее время их обдумывания  1 минута 31 секунда . У Аlex тоже 2 вопроса, которые он решал 4 минуты 24 секунды.

Comment: А, всё, теперь понял. Но ответить попробую завтра уже

Comment: И всё же приведите хотя бы какой-то кусок данных в воспроизводимом виде - в виде текста, чтобы можно было запустить и датафрейм хотя бы частично заполнился.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['0 days 00:00:01', '0 days 00:00:07', '0 days 00:02:03', '0 days 00:05:23',
                            '0 days 00:06:34', '0 days 00:08:09', '0 days 00:10:53', '0 days 00:11:36',
                            '0 days 00:14:04', '0 days 00:15:48', '0 days 00:17:12', '0 days 00:19:29',
                            '0 days 00:21:45'],
                   'name': ['Max', 'Alex', 'Maria', 'Sam', 'Max', 'Maria', 'Sam', 'Alex', 'John', 'Maria', 'John',
                            'Sam', 'Alex']})
df.time = df.time.apply(pd.Timedelta)
# конец подготовки данных
df = df.assign(time=lambda x: x.time.diff().shift(-1, fill_value=pd.Timedelta('0'))).groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()
print(df)
```

```
    name            time
0   Alex 0 days 00:04:24
1   John 0 days 00:04:01
2  Maria 0 days 00:07:28
3    Max 0 days 00:01:41
4    Sam 0 days 00:04:10
```

Для `Мax` правильное значение получается не 00:01:31, а 00:01:41, поскольку первое вхождение 00:06 (00:07-00:01), второе 01:35 (08:09-06:34).
И остается непонятным, сколько времени потратил `Alex` в последней строке.